# How do I filter a select list in Laravel Nova that uses a BelongsTo field?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-nova

I have a Quiz Resource that is used to define the questions and answers in a quiz.

A BelongsTo field is used to select the creator of that quiz - it pulls this information out of my users table.  However, I only want to pull users that have the 'role_id' of 1 or 2.

I am trying to use the relatable function but it does't seem to want to recognise its existence.

My Quiz Resource:

```
class Quiz extends Resource
{
    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = 'App\Quiz\Quiz';

public function fields(Request $request)
    {

        return [
            ...

            BelongsTo::make('User', 'users','\App\Nova\User')
                ->display(function($user){
                        return $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
                }),

            ...
        ];
    }
}
```

My Nova Users model:

```
class User extends Resource
{

     public static $model = 'App\Account\User';

public static function relatableQuizzes(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        return $query->where('role_id', 1);
    }
}
```

I have tried using different function names including: 
relatableUsers
relatableusers
relatableQuiz
relatableQuizs
relatableQuizzes

but each time there is no effect.

How can I filter this list of users by role id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are relating `Users` from the `Quiz` resource, did you try it the other way round?

```php
class Quiz extends Resource
{
    // ...

    public static function relatableUsers(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        return $query->where('role_id', 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't I thought I had to do it from the other way around. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try some like this

```php
  public function options(Request $request)
    {

        $supplier = Supplier::all()->mapWithKeys(function($item) {
            return [
                $item['name'] => $item['item']
            ];
        }); 

        return $supplier;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereIn` method in your query like below:

```
$users = User::whereIn('role_id', [1,2])->get();
```